# How to cast to unsigned vector type after using __builtin_msa_ld_*

Tags: c, mips, simd, intrinsics

I'm evaluating [MIPS SIMD Architecture (MSA)](https://www.mips.com/downloads/mips-simd-architecture/) programming using the [Codescape GCC Toolchain](https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/codescape-mips-sdk/). There's not much information out there about MSA and builtins. (As far as I can tell there's only two MSA cpu's, the P5600 and Warrior I6400, and they first became available several years ago).

My test program is below.

```
#include <msa.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ALIGN16 __attribute__((aligned(16)))

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ALIGN16 uint32_t a[] = {64, 128, 256, 512};
    ALIGN16 uint32_t b[] = {1024, 2048, 4096, 8192};
    ALIGN16 uint32_t c[4];

    v4u32 va = __builtin_msa_ld_w (a, 0);
    v4u32 vb = __builtin_msa_ld_w (b, 0);

    v4u32 vc = __builtin_msa_adds_u_w (va, vb);
    __builtin_msa_st_w (vc, c, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the program results in the errors shown below. The problem is, the [vector loads return a signed vector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/MIPS-SIMD-Architecture-Built-in-Functions.html#MIPS-SIMD-Architecture-Built-in-Functions) but my vectors are unsigned. I have a similar problem with the vector stores.

```
// The 4 vector loads provided through builtins
v16i8 __builtin_msa_ld_b (void *, imm_n512_511);    // byte
v8i16 __builtin_msa_ld_h (void *, imm_n1024_1022);  // half word
v4i32 __builtin_msa_ld_w (void *, imm_n2048_2044);  // word
v2i64 __builtin_msa_ld_d (void *, imm_n4096_4088);  // double word
```

(The `imm_n512_511` and friends is discussed in the GCC manual at [6.59.16 MIPS SIMD Architecture (MSA) Support](http://embarc.org/man-pages/gcc/MIPS-SIMD-Architecture-_0028MSA_0029-Support.html)).

I read MIPS paper(?) at [MIPS SIMD Architecture](https://www.mips.com/downloads/mips-simd-architecture/) but it does not discuss how to convert between integral vector types. There are lots of floating-point conversion instructions, but nothing for integral types.

Is a simple cast the preferred way to convert between integral vector types? Or is there something else I should be doing?

---

```
MSA$ mips-img-linux-gnu-gcc.exe -mmsa test.c -c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:12:2: note: use -flax-vector-conversions to permit conversions between ve
ctors with differing element types or numbers of subparts
  v4u32 va = __builtin_msa_ld_w (a, 0);
  ^~~~~
test.c:12:13: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'v4u32 {aka __vec
tor(4) unsigned int}' using type '__vector(4) int'
  v4u32 va = __builtin_msa_ld_w (a, 0);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:13:13: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'v4u32 {aka __vec
tor(4) unsigned int}' using type '__vector(4) int'
  v4u32 vb = __builtin_msa_ld_w (b, 0);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:16:22: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of '__builtin_msa_st_w'
  __builtin_msa_st_w (vc, c, 0);
                      ^~
test.c:16:22: note: expected '__vector(4) int' but argument is of type 'v4u32 {a
ka __vector(4) unsigned int}'
```

Comment: why don't you use `va` and `vb` instead of `a` and `b` ? Also doc say, "The load/store instructions do not require 128-bit (16-byte) memory address
alignment.", so I don't think you need `ALIGN16`. I don't think you need to worry "The MSA complements the well-established MIPS architecture with a set of more than 150 new instructions operating
on 32 vector registers of 8-, 16-, 32-, and 64-bit integer, 16-and 32-bit fixed- point, or 32- and 64-bit floating-point
data elements....", look like a simple cast will do the job correctly (if of course the real integer are unsigned).

Comment: Thanks @Stargateur - The `ALIGN16` came from [MIPS SIMD Architecture](https://www.mips.com/downloads/mips-simd-architecture/), Section 5.1 Vector Data Types and Intrinsics, page 10: *"It is recommended aligning the vector data to the size of the vector registers"*.  I think the importance of *"size of the vector registers"* is, DSP has 64-bit vector registers, while MSA has 128-bit vector registers.

Comment: Well, recommanded is different of required, maybe it's better to align them, I didn't read all documentation. Also I think they didn't add specific instruction for loading unsigned to save some instruction, because I suppose their load work on both sign. Maybe, you should add yourself the wrapper function that will cast the vector for you when you load and store unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you use casts and `-flax-vector-conversions`, or use an union type to represent the vector registers and explicitly work on that union type. GCC explicitly supports that form of type-punning.

For example, you could declare an `msa128` type,

```
typedef union __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) {
    v2u64   u64;
    v2i64   i64;
    v2f64   f64;
    v4u32   u32;
    v4i32   i32;
    v4f32   f32;
    v8u16   u16;
    v8i16   i16;
    v16u8   u8;
    v16i8   i8;
} msa128;
```

and then have your code work explicitly on the `msa128` type.  Your example program could be written as

```
    uint32_t a[4] = { 64, 128, 256, 512 };
    uint32_t b[4] = { 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192 };
    uint32_t c[4];
    msa128   va, vb, vc;

    va.i32 = __builtin_msa_ld_w(a, 0);
    vb.i32 = __builtin_msa_ld_w(b, 0);
    vc.u32 = __builtin_msa_adds_u_w(va.u32, vb.u32);
    __builtin_msa_st_w(vc.i32, c, 0);
```

Obviously, it becomes quite annoying to remember the exact type one needs to use, so some static inline helper functions would definitely be handy:

```
static inline msa128  msa128_load64(const void *from, const int imm)
{ return (msa128){ .i64 = __builtin_msa_ld_d(from, imm); } }

static inline msa128  msa128_load32(const void *from, const int imm)
{ return (msa128){ .i32 = __builtin_msa_ld_w(from, imm); } }

static inline msa128  msa128_load16(const void *from, const int imm)
{ return (msa128){ .i16 = __builtin_msa_ld_h(from, imm); } }

static inline msa128  msa128_load8(const void *from, const int imm)
{ return (msa128){ .i8  = __builtin_msa_ld_b(from, imm); } }

static inline void  msa128_store64(const msa128 val, void *to, const int imm)
{ __builtin_msa_st_d(val.i64, to, imm); }

static inline void  msa128_store32(const msa128 val, void *to, const int imm)
{ __builtin_msa_st_w(val.i32, to, imm); }

static inline void  msa128_store16(const msa128 val, void *to, const int imm)
{ __builtin_msa_st_h(val.i16, to, imm); }

static inline void  msa128_store8(const msa128 val, void *to, const int imm)
{ __builtin_msa_st_b(val.i8, to, imm); }
```

For example, the binary AND, OR, NOR, and XOR operations are

```
static inline msa128  msa128_and(const msa128 a, const msa128 b)
{ return (msa128){ .u8 = __builtin_msa_and_v(a, b) }; }

static inline msa128  msa128_or(const msa128 a, const msa128 b)
{ return (msa128){ .u8 = __builtin_msa_or_v(a, b) }; }

static inline msa128  msa128_nor(const msa128 a, const msa128 b)
{ return (msa128){ .u8 = __builtin_msa_nor_v(a, b) }; }

static inline msa128  msa128_xor(const msa128 a, const msa128 b)
{ return (msa128){ .u8 = __builtin_msa_xor_v(a, b) }; }
```

It probably wouldn't hurt creating some macros to represent the vectors in array form:

```
#define  MSA128_U64(...)  ((msa128){ .u64 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_I64(...)  ((msa128){ .i64 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_F64(...)  ((msa128){ .f64 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_U32(...)  ((msa128){ .u32 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_I32(...)  ((msa128){ .i32 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_F32(...)  ((msa128){ .f32 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_U16(...)  ((msa128){ .u16 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_I16(...)  ((msa128){ .i16 = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_U8(...)   ((msa128){ .u8  = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
#define  MSA128_I8(...)   ((msa128){ .i8  = { __VA_ARGS__ }})
```

The reason I suggest this GCC-specific approach is that the builtins are GCC specific anyway.  Other than the union type, it is very close to how GCC implements Intel/AMD vector intrinsics in `<immintrin.h>`.

Comment: Thanks @Nominal. Eventually I need to use this in C++, so I can't use the union trick. (Sorry abut that. I refrained from adding C++ tag because of the folks who comment C and C++ are different languages...).

Comment: @jww your question is the typical case where tag both C and C++ will be wrong, if you need answer for both language, you must create two question and a C++ expert or C will decide if the answer is correct for both C and C++, and will juste close as duplicate. For example, I could answer (and I did but in comment) the C part but I could not be sure for the C++ part as I never read the C++ standard. Unless your question is asking for compatibility issue (a specific question), don't tag both language.

Comment: Thanks @nominal. Yes, the union trick can be undefined behavior in C++ *if* you access the inactive member (which is relied upon here). Also see [Accessing inactive union member and undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/608639) I found I can squash the warnings in a manner that keeps C and C++ happy by taking the address of the vector variable and using a `memcpy`, but it is a code wart. It is too bad MIPS does not have casts like ARM intrinsics (like `vreinterpretq_i32_u32`).

Comment: Thanks again @nominal. If a MIPS expert comes along and offers something better I may need to move the accept.

Comment: @jww: No worries! To me, only the applicability/usefulness of the answer matters.  (I admit, I am one of those to whom C and C++ differences matter -- but in my defense, it is because the answers are (or should be) completely different, to be efficient. This *is* one of those cases.)  As I use C for my low-level code, and haven't used the vector intrinsics in C++, I'm not sure what the best solution in C++ is, but I'll take a look later today, and edit my answer if I find anything better than the memcpy() way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that works with both C and C++. It performs a `memcpy` on the register variables. The inline functions borrow from ARM NEON support. ARM provides casts for the NEON vectors, like `vreinterpretq_u64_u8`. The `inline` on the functions requires C99.

```c
#include <msa.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

inline v4i32 reinterpretq_i32_u32(const v4u32 val) {
    v4i32 res;
    memcpy(&res, &val, sizeof(res));
    return res;
}

inline v4u32 reinterpretq_u32_i32(const v4i32 val) {
    v4u32 res;
    memcpy(&res, &val, sizeof(res));
    return res;
}

#define ALIGN16 __attribute__((aligned(16)))

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ALIGN16 uint32_t a[] = {64, 128, 256, 512};
    ALIGN16 uint32_t b[] = {1024, 2048, 4096, 8192};
    ALIGN16 uint32_t c[4];

    v4u32 va = reinterpretq_u32_i32(__builtin_msa_ld_w (a, 0));
    v4u32 vb = reinterpretq_u32_i32(__builtin_msa_ld_w (b, 0));

    v4u32 vc = __builtin_msa_adds_u_w (va, vb);
    __builtin_msa_st_w (reinterpretq_i32_u32(vc), c, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

And a compile at `-O3` (it is clean at `-Wall -Wextra`):

```
MSA$ mips-img-linux-gnu-gcc.exe -O3 -mmsa test.c -c
MSA$
```

And a disassembly looks like it passes the sniff test:

```
MSA$ mips-img-linux-gnu-objdump.exe --disassemble test.o

test.o:     file format elf32-tradbigmips

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
   0:   27bdffc8        addiu      sp,sp,-56
   4:   3c020000        lui        v0,0x0
   8:   24420000        addiu      v0,v0,0
   c:   78001062        ld.w       $w1,0(v0)
  10:   3c020000        lui        v0,0x0
  14:   24420000        addiu      v0,v0,0
  18:   78001022        ld.w       $w0,0(v0)
  1c:   79c10010        adds_u.w   $w0,$w0,$w1
  20:   7802e826        st.w       $w0,8(sp)
  24:   93a2000b        lbu        v0,11(sp)
  28:   03e00009        jr         ra
  2c:   27bd0038        addiu      sp,sp,56
```

---

For completeness, GCC 6.3.0:

```
MSA$ mips-img-linux-gnu-gcc.exe --version
mips-img-linux-gnu-gcc.exe (Codescape GNU Tools 2017.10-05 for MIPS IMG Linux) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: I wonder if using `typedef char msa128 __attribute__((vector_size (16), aligned (16)));` as the basic vector type suffices. Since it is a character type, GCC allows it to alias any other type, so you can cast between e.g. `v2u64 a;` and `v4f32 b;` using `a = (v2u64)((msa128)(b));` and `b = (v4f32)((msa128)(a));` (in both g++ (`-std=gnu++14`) and gcc (`-std=gnu11`) using GCC 5.4.0).